# react-native build failed: Xcode 7.2.1, react-native cli v : 2.0.1 (MacOSX 10.10.5)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm new to react native. Initialised a new project by running react-native init project-name and then running it on Xcode but the build was failed....again and again.

By looking at solutions posted by other users, I commented out this line of code in file RCTPlatform.m :

```
 // case UIUserInterfaceIdiomCarPlay:
 // return @"carplay";
```

That's one issue solved, but then when I tried to build the project it gave me another error:

[image]

Please can someone help me out. I have no idea what went wrong. I haven't even started any coding work on the project.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [React Native Getting Started](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) documentation, "make sure it (XCode) is version 8 or higher." In order to upgrade your XCode version to greater than 8.0, you will first need to upgrade your MacOSX to Sierra. You can do this in the App Store. Good luck!